# Shifting a symbol vertically in Math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, vertical-alignment

I have a small nitpicking query

I have:

```
$S\sqsubset\mathbf{P}$
```

and noticed that the `\sqsubset` symbol is a bit too low (off centered) for my liking. Is it possible to shift it up slightly?

Comment: Note that `\sqsubset` is designed to be so low for the case that you have descenders as in the letter `y`. But I see why you want to raise it when there are no descenders as in `S` and `P`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can redefine `\sqsubset` to take an optional argument that would raise it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsfonts
\let\oldsqsubset\sqsubset
\renewcommand{\sqsubset}[1][0pt]{%
  \mathrel{\raisebox{#1}{$\oldsqsubset$}}%
}
\begin{document}
$S\sqsubset\mathbf{P} \quad S\sqsubset[5pt]\mathbf{P} \quad S\sqsubset[1pt]\mathbf{P}$
\end{document}
```

The updated `\sqsubset` is set as a binary relation `\mathrel`. Note that if you want to use square brackets *after* `\sqsubset`, you need to surround it with braces. The new usage is `\sqsubset[<len>]` where `<len>` is any recognized (La)TeX length.

Comment: @MobiusPizza: Note that you can also use a negative `<len>` to *lower* the symbol.

Comment: What if you want the symbol to be raised proportionally in subscripts and subsubscripts too? The `\raisebox` 'resets' to the normal size and I cannot figure out how to make it preserve the current size.

Comment: Oh I found that we can [save the current style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114658), so that solves my question.