# How to make expectation symbol and max symbol line up

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Suppose you prefer the max symbol to be centered (height-wise) compared to a capitol letter that is taller. How would you do that. For example, below

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{equation*}
         \max_{r_t} \left\{ 
         \mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} r_t^t \right]
         \right\}
    \end{equation*}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like the max symbol moved slightly up so it lines up with the center of the expectation symbol.

Comment: By default, the *baselines* of the strings "max", "E", and "r" are all aligned. Are you saying that this is *not* what you want?

Comment: I suppose you could achieve the desired effect by replacing `\mathbb{E}` with `\vcenter{\hbox{$\mathbb{E}$}}`. Instead of raising the string "max", it lowers the `\mathbb{E}` particle.

Comment: There is a somewhat related process being sought [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51387/slightly-alter-a-symbol-position).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than *raise* the height of `\max_{r_t}`, I would *lower* the `\mathbb{E}` particle, making it look more like a purely symbolic entity (rather than an uppercase letter). One way to do this is to encase it in a `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` set of directives.

[image]

Note that this method (as well as the one you initially proposed) "works", typographically speaking, only if there's a large symbol (such as `\sum` and `\int`) nearby. If the surrounding material is mostly text aligned on a common baseline, lowering the particle `\mathbb{E}` would probably look bizarre.

Incidentally, I would not use `\left` and `\right` to size the fence symbols in this formula, as doing so results in fences that are too large and thus dominate the material they enclose. Instead of `\left` and `\right`, I would use `\biggl` and `\biggr`, striking a balance between the material enclosed by the fences and the fences themselves.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \[
         \max_{r_t} \biggl\{ 
         \mathbb{E}
         \biggl[ \, \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} r_t^t \biggr]
         \biggr\}
      \quad\text{vs.}\quad
         \max_{r_t} \biggl\{ 
         \vcenter{\hbox{$\mathbb{E}$}}
         \biggl[ \, \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} r_t^t \biggr]
         \biggr\}
    \]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want the expectation symbol is slightly moved down, but my advice is: don't. Letters are expected to hang on the baseline, just like `max` does.

The method is simply to say

```
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\nolimits
```

because a one letter `\mathop` is automatically centered around the formula axis (like `\sum` is).

However, the same example shows why this is not really a good idea.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\expect}{\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\nolimits}

\begin{document}
\[
\max_{r_t} \biggl\{ 
  \mathbb{E}
  \biggl[ \, \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} r_t^t \biggr]
\biggr\}
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\max_{r_t} \biggl\{ 
  \expect
  \biggl[ \, \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} r_t^t \biggr]
\biggr\}
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\expect(a)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For one-letter "operators" such as `\mathbb{E}`, is there a meaningful difference in the output produced by `\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\nolimits` and `\vcenter{\hbox{$\mathbb{E}$}}`?

Comment: @Mico Yes: the former will work also in subscripts/superscripts with the correct size, the latter won't.

Comment: Hopefully, `\mathbb{E}` will never show up in either subscript or superscript form when used in operator mode...